# Put the legend of pandas bar plot with secondary y axis in front of bars

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, jupyter-notebook

I have a pandas DataFrame with a secondary y axis and I need a bar plot with the legend in front of the bars. Currently, one set of bars is in front of the legend. If possible, I would also like to place the legend in the lower-left corner. Any ideas appreciated!

I have attempted to set the legend=false and add a custom legend, but it has the same issue. I've tried reordering the columns but there's no way to clear a space for this on the chart.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_y = pd.DataFrame([['jade',12,800],['lime',12,801],['leaf',12,802], 
       ['puke',12,800]], columns=['Territory','Cuisines','Restaurants'])
df_y.set_index('Territory', inplace=True)

plt.figure()
ax=df_y.plot(kind='bar', secondary_y=['Restaurants'])
ax.set_ylabel('Cuisines')
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Restaurants')
plt.show()
```

One set of bars appears behind the legend, and one set appears in front of the legend. The link below goes to an image showing the problem. Thank you!

[image: link to image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create the legend yourself.

Use the color cycler to get the colors correct when zipped with the columns. Make sure to set `legend=False` in the barplot. `loc=3` is the lower left.

```
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df_y.plot(kind='bar', secondary_y=['Restaurants'], legend=False, ax=ax)
ax.set_ylabel('Cuisines')
ax.right_ax.set_ylabel('Restaurants')

L = [mpatches.Patch(color=c, label=col) 
     for col,c in zip(df_y.columns, plt.rcParams['axes.prop_cycle'].by_key()['color'])]

plt.legend(handles=L, loc=3)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I am going to spend some time learning more about this library and how this was generated. Exactly what I was looking for.