# Pandas Plot Function with Secondary Axis - controlling legend location

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I am plotting two columns from my dataframe onto 1 plot with two y-axis. I am using the inbuilding "secondary_y" option in the plot function, but it seems to plot the legend where it wants and I cannot control it. See below, this is a problem as you can't see what is on the legend. Ugh.

Code:

```
experiments_summary = pd.concat([all_results_porto.groupby(group_by_var)['CPU Time'].mean(),all_results_porto.groupby(group_by_var)['Average Journey Time'].mean()], axis = 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8,3))
experiments_summary.plot(kind='bar', secondary_y= 'Average Journey Time',rot = 45 ,ax = ax,grid = True)

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Here is the plot:

[image]

UPDATE: See below post for solution

[stackoverflow.com/a/56877283/6361531](https://%20stackoverflow.com/a/56877283/6361531)

Comment: Is there any reason why you're using `plt.subplots` ? I would recommend to directly use figsize in `experiments_summary.plot()`

Comment: Thanks for coming back to me. Actually there is no partuclar reason for using subplots to be honest. I tried your suggestion but it's given the same result.

Comment: Could you provide sample data so that it's easier for the community to help you ?

Comment: Good idea - i've updated original post with code snippet including data so problem can be replicated

Comment: Actually it's different data - but it gives the same problem

Comment: Look at this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/56877283/6361531 by @ALollz

Comment: Thanks this has solved my issue. Not an ideal solution (not that i'm complaining!) as you still need to manually put in the legend handles - in my case not an issue as they'll always be the same. I guess this is a limitation of using seconday axis function in this way.

Comment: Be sure to upvote @ALollz posts.  He did a great job.